# How to receive notification on JMS disconnect?

Tags: jms, failover

I'm using JMS to talk to ActiveMQ. I had to disable failover for ActiveMQ because I need to handle it myself.

So instead of using `failover//tcp//localhost:61616` I used `tcp//localhost:61616`.

If I close ActiveMQ server and try to send a message, I'll receive an exception.

```
javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The Session is closed
```

But how can I be notified when the connection with the server is lost ASAP?

The reason I'm not using the ActiveMQ's failover is because in production I will be using MQSeries. Therefore, I need a method that's pure JMS and not specific to any particular implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but [TransportListener](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/activemq-core/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/transport/TransportListener.html) can help you.

Here is a sample of using it,

```
connection = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUrl).createConnection();
ActiveMQConnection cc = (ActiveMQConnection)connection;
cc.addTransportListener(new YourTransportListener());
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I can't use it because it's not plain JMS.  I found that I could add  connection.setExceptionListener(new ExceptionListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onException(JMSException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     System.out.println(e);
    }
   });   for a JMSConnection.  I'm notify when I client try to push something : javax.jms.JMSException: java.io.EOFException   but I guess that I can't get something more meaningful.

Comment: Look like I can do a reconnection when I receive a exception within the ExceptionListener.  I'll go with that. thanks for your help